# Saving the output to a file when launching xfce4 terminal when using a --command switch

Tags: thunar, xfce4-terminal

I'm trying to setup a custom action for thunar (these are the custom context menu commands) that will map all the files within the folder structure I'm in.

If I was in terminal, all I'd have to do is input the following command while I'm within the directory I want to map:

```
find . -type f > content.txt
```

To map this as a custom action, I tried the following command

```
xfce4-terminal --working-directory=%d --command='find . -type f > %d/content.txt'
```

and it doesn't work, despite that fact that this one which is almost the same does work:

```
xfce4-terminal --hold --working-directory=/home/lapinot/Downloads/%d -command='find . -type f'
```

The only notable difference between the two is that I'm trying to feed the outcome into a text file via `>` switch in the one that isn't working.

Anyone has any ideas how I can get this to work? Note that %d is referring to the directory I'm in in thunar.

**Update:** I've re-posted the question on xfce's forum, I post an answer here if they give me feedback.